# Scraping table data with htmlagility pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have a table like below. I want to scrape the 1st and 4th column of each row of that table .

[image]

The structure of the table is like that:

[image]

There is a `b` tag of each data

I tried something like this. But I failed to gain my result

```
 HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
 HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://www.islam4you.info/contents/names/ma.php");
 HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//b");


 double k = 5;

 try
 {
     foreach (HtmlNode n in nodes)
     {
                
        if (k != 0)
        {
          if ((k % 5) == 1)
          {
              link = n.InnerHtml;
              nam_list.Add(link);
          }

          if ((k % 5) == 4)
          {

              link = n.InnerHtml;
              meng_list.Add(link);
          }
         }
         k++;
       }
  }
  catch (NullReferenceException)
  {
       MessageBox.Show("No link found");
  }
```

How can I get the 1st column's and 4th column's data from that table ???

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It might sound overkill but I think it would be better to use a library in this case. It's just better for maintenance.

Check out how easy it is using [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery)

```
[TestFixture]
public class HtmlParse
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {

        var dom =
            CQ.Create(
                @"<table><tbody> <tr><td><b>Aadam</b></td></tr> <tr><td></td></tr> <tr><td></td></tr> <tr><td></td></tr> <tr><td><b>Earth</b></td></tr></tbody></table>");

        var results = dom["table tr:nth-child(1) b, table tr:nth-child(5) b"];

        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result.InnerText);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@bordercolor='#111111'][1]")
                .Descendants("tr")
                .Select(tr => tr.Descendants("td").Select(td => td.InnerText).ToList())
                .Where(x => x.Count() == 5)
                .ToList();
```